# Pods getting restarted after containerd and kubelet service restarts

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, containerd

As part of configuration changes take place, both containerd and kubelet serivces need restart. Upon restarting services, all the pods running on the node getting restarted. I've checked the events show as below. I was unable to find the reasons why containers also restarting. Can anyone please suggest.

````
7m29s       Normal   SandboxChanged   pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
7m29s       Normal   Killing          pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Stopping container fluentd
7m15s       Normal   Pulled           pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Container image "10.44.10.17/app1/fluentd-logs:1.94.0" already present on machine
7m15s       Normal   Created          pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Created container step-one
7m15s       Normal   Started          pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Started container step-one
7m14s       Normal   Pulling          pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Pulling image "10.44.10.17/app1/fluentd-logs:1.94.0"
7m14s       Normal   Pulled           pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Successfully pulled image "10.44.10.17/app1/fluentd-logs:1.94.0" in 77.028924ms
7m14s       Normal   Created          pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Created container fluentd
7m14s       Normal   Started          pod/fluentd-ds-bqs9r   Started container fluentd```



OS / Versions used:
OS : Ubuntu Jammy
containerd:1.6.9-1

kubeadm : 1.24.15                                 
kubebootstrap :  3.4.1-20231013T175935Z-5d85a5e
kubectl : 1.24.15
kubelet : 1.24.15
````

Comment: The answer is there in your question itself, kubelet is a service which is responsible for managing the pods when it gets restarted the pod will get terminated and recreated as a result the containers present in the pod will also undergo these restarts. If you want to prevent the application data from getting corrupted due to these restarts you need to configure graceful termination for pods

Comment: Restarting `kubelet` doesn't cause containers to restart. Restarting `containerd` can cause containers to restart but it is possibly a bug.

Comment: I tried upgrading containerd version with 1.6.12 where also we see pods restart happening.

FYI : First we restarting containerd which is not restarting pods. When we restart kubelet after containerd, we see this problem.

Comment: @Rama This [blog](https://foxutech.medium.com/kubernetes-pod-graceful-shutdown-how-a9a46e0b1e53) written by foxutech has a detailed explanation on how to configure graceful termination of the pods. Hope this might help you

Comment: Like @AlexD said in general restarting the kubelet service should not affect the pods, however we are making some config changes and then we are restarting the kubelet service and containerd service in order to get these changes reflected a pod restart might have happened. There is a similar answer written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912537/does-restarting-kubelet-stop-all-nodes) but it is too old and there might be some new changes, will ping you here if I found any relevant docs.

Comment: @Rama in your case since you have upgraded the containerd version it caused the restart

Comment: Hi @KranthiveerDontineni, Even we do services restarts in general, we see this behaviour. We have another cluster which is running with Ubuntu Bionic and containerd-1.6.9 where no restart happening even we do manual restarts.

Comment: @Rama can you check your cluster logs and update any error or message you find in them here